# I'm trying to produce sound in Android only with the headphones

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, audiotrack

I'm developing an App using Flutter and I only would like to emit sound through the headphones or the top speaker (The one used for phone calls). Currently it uses the big speaker and headphones at the same time but i would like to change it so I can only listen when the headphone is connected. The current package that i'm using to stream and play audio is https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream.

This is the code for initializing the player:

```
private fun initializePlayer(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    mPlayerSampleRate = call.argument<Int>("sampleRate") ?: mPlayerSampleRate
    debugLogging = call.argument<Boolean>("showLogs") ?: false
    mPlayerFormat = AudioFormat.Builder()
            .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
            .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO)
            .setSampleRate(mPlayerSampleRate)
            .build()

    mPlayerBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(mPlayerSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)

    if (mAudioTrack?.state == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
        mAudioTrack?.release()
    }

    /*
    // I have tried with different examples but they don't work

    var value = this.pluginContext?.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

    //For phone ear piece
    value.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION;
    value.stopBluetoothSco();
    value.isBluetoothScoOn = false;
    value.isSpeakerphoneOn = false;

    //For BT
    value.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    value.startBluetoothSco();
    value.setBluetoothScoOn(true);

    //For phone speaker(loadspeaker)
    value.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    value.stopBluetoothSco();
    value.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
    value.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

     */

    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
            .build()
    mAudioTrack = AudioTrack(audioAttributes, mPlayerFormat, mPlayerBufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM, AudioManager.AUDIO_SESSION_ID_GENERATE)

    result.success(true)
    sendPlayerStatus(SoundStreamStatus.Initialized)
}
```

And this is the code to play the audio:

```
private fun startPlayer(result: Result) {
    try {
        if (mAudioTrack?.state == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {
            result.success(true)
            return
        }
        var value = this.pluginContext!!.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

        if(value.isWiredHeadsetOn()){
            mAudioTrack!!.play()
        }

        sendPlayerStatus(SoundStreamStatus.Playing)
        result.success(true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        result.error(SoundStreamErrors.FailedToPlay.name, "Failed to start Player", e.localizedMessage)
    }
}
```

The code is used in the Android part with kotlin.

Thanks.

Comment: `FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED` doesn't seem like something you should add if you don't want the audio to be played in the loudspeaker.

Comment: @Michael Yes, that fixed my problem. 
Thank you for your help and quick response :)